# Linear programming optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I need some hint, where I can find programming algorithm for next optimization problem. I need to write a code to solve some system of equations with several restrictions. 
Let's assume, we have $N$ pairs of numbers $(a_{i}, b_{i})$ and $N$ coefficients $q_{i}$ with values $(0;1)$. I need to find values of coefficients $q_{i}$ that will satisfy next restrictions:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sum_{0}^{N} (q_{i}*b_{i})}{\sum_{0}^{N} (q_{i}*a_{i})}\approx 0.75 (\Delta = 0.002)\\
\\
\frac{\sum_{0}^{N} (q_{i}*a_{i})}{\sum_{0}^{N} a_{i}}\approx 0.01\\
q_{i} \epsilon [0;1]\\
a_{i} > 0;b_{i} \geqslant 0\\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

For example:
$$N=100;\\
a_{0..99}=1;\\
b_{0}=0.75;b_{1..99}=0;$$
Then the answer will be:
$$q_{0}=1; q_{1..99}=0$$

Comment: What do the right arrows mean?

Comment: Almost equal ("approaches") with some delta (for first equation delta is 0.002)

Comment: The goal is to minimize difference of sums with target values.